# error TS2339 while accessing an ngform outside a div

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, ng-bootstrap

I have an angular project where I used ngb-accordion from ng-bootstrap to display some details. My accordion is responsive. I have included forms inside each accordion. I have a requirement where I want to display a specific icon above the accordion panel depending on whether the form inside is valid or invalid. Like when the form is filled inside the accordion I would like to display a bootstrap tick icon , if it is wrong then I want it to display a cross mark icon. I tried writing a `ngIf` directive that checks whether the form is valid or not for the div containing icon.

Below is the code where i tried to implement the above said functionality for one accordion

HTML File

```
 <head>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <div *ngIf="form1.invalid">
        &nbsp;
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
            <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"
            style="color: red;"/>
          </svg>
    </div>
    
    <div>
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
    <ngb-panel id="toggle-1" title="Primary Details" >
      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
        <form #form1="ngForm" style="padding-left:20px;">
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">First Name<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                <input type="text" ngModel name="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName">
              </div>
           
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Last Name<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                <input type="text" name="LastName" class="form-control" id="LastName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Organization<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
              </div>
              </form> 
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </ngb-accordion>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
    <ngb-panel id="toggle-2" title="Secondary Details">
      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
        <form #form2="ngForm" style="padding-left:20px;">
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Address<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                <input type="text" name="Address" class="form-control" id="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dropdown-test" class="control-label">City<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
              
                <select class="form-control" name="dropdown-test">
                <option>select an option</option>
                <option>option2</option>
                <option>option3</option>
                <option>option4</option>
                <option>option5</option>
              </select>
              </div>  
             
              </form> 
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
    
  </ngb-accordion>
  <br>
  <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
    <ngb-panel id="toggle-3" title="More Details">
      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
        <form #form3="ngForm" style="padding-left:20px;">
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Email<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                <input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control" id="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Phone<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                <input type="number" name="Phone" class="form-control" id="name">
              </div>  
             
              </form> 
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
    
  </ngb-accordion>
  
  
 </body>
```

CSS file

```
    input[type="text"],
select.form-control{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
input[type="number"],
select.form-control{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
select.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color:rgb(31, 14, 187);
}
input[type="number"]:focus,
select.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color:darkred;
}
```

At the line  `<div *ngIf="form1.invalid">` it throws me an error saying **src/app/collapsedemo/collapsedemo.component.html:9:21 - error TS2339: Property 'form1' does not exist** **on type 'CollapsedemoComponent'.**

Please tell me what am I doing wrong. I will include the picture of working app without the `ngIf` directive when the form is not filled.

[image]

Also please suggest me an alternative if there is any, where I can display those icons in the acoordion panel itself just before the title like lets say before the "Primary Details" title in the above picture rather than above the ngb-panel.The ultimate goal is to display a green tick when the form details are filled and a cross mark when it is not filled inside the accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is not available at this position, as it is located deeper in the nested structure and you are outside of it.

You can achieve what you want with the ViewChild-directive and a method. I'll show you how.

**Step I**

Get the ViewChild of your form in your TS-file.

```
@ViewChild('form1') myForm: NgForm | undefined;
```

**Step II**

Write a method with which you can get the state of your view child.

***Attention!*** You will run into the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` if you don't wait. This is because your form's state is `undefined` at start and when it gets `true` the rest of your HTML is not finally rendered by Angular. So I figured a way to handle this race condition.

```
// shows whether the view is rendered entirely
private viewRendered = false;

// returns the current state of your form1
myFormIsInvalid(): boolean {

   // only return the actual state, when the view is rendered entirely
   if (this.viewRendered) {
       return !(this.myForm && this.myForm.valid);
   }

   return false;
}
```

And then we need to put a little timeout into `ngOnInit()`, in order to set your method free when the entire form is supposed to be loaded.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // after 250ms set the method myFormIsValid() free to return the actual value
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.viewRendered = true;
    }, 250);
}
```

**Step III**

```
In your HTML: Use the method here to get the state of the form

<div *ngIf="myFormIsInvalid()">
```

Comment: Thank you! But the icon disappears when the accordion is closed. I want it to  stay all the time whenever the form is unfilled. Also the icon doesn't disappear  even after I fill all the fields.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't catch that you wanted to see the icon when the form is invalid. I edited the method name and the result it returns. Please, try again.

Comment: i tried modifying it can you check it out please?https://pastebin.com/0eSihkDp but its still not working

Comment: You have to negate your code to `if (!this.myForm?.valid){}`. As I said I thought you wanted to see the icon when the form is valid. But its method's name should better be `myFormIsInvalid()` now. Just to make it concise. Try again, please.

Comment: i'm sorry if i had not made my requirements very clear.I'll say it again. I have two divs one containing the 'X' icon that has to be rendered all the time when the form is invalid . Another div that contains the tick mark icon that has to be rendered when the form is valid.I intend to use an ngif else directive to make this possible as i have mentioned in my previous comment in the link i posted.

Comment: Also do you know the reason why the icons don't render when we close the accordion? I want them to be displayed irrespective of whether the accordion is closed or opened,touched or untouched

Comment: Okay. Back to square 1. I changed the method in my example once again. It returns true when the state is VALID and it returns false when the state is FALSE or UNDEFINED. I also commented at the bottom how to use it for both icons. You have to negate the returned result with the `!` operator directly in the HTML, when you want to say "show if NOT VALID".

The icons don't show because closed Accordions tend to clear the entire DOM. The form is not there any more. It gets rerendered when you open the accordion again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231682/discussion-between-ananthhokage-and-lynx-242).

Comment: Sorry, I am at work now. Chat isn't possible here. But glad to see that it workes now for you. :)